# How can I build Addons to visual studio(ankh)

Tags: visual-studio, svn, add-on

I daily make a few commits and publish my webservice and I daily make a few mistakes with this, because I forget about doing update. Is there any way to get mesaage box with question "Did you update changes ?). This message bo could arrise while I'm click publish or commit.

I use vs 2008, tortoise, and ankh svn.

Comment: The problem is that you're publishing from your machine rather than from a build server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solving all these issues (this includes files which someone forgot to add etc.) is by always building/testing/publishing from a fresh checkout, preferably on a tag, preferably on a dedicated machine.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to it really, just remember to get latest version, built, run tests and then update.

Answer (score 0):

As other's pointed out , I dont think you could do much about forcing an update before publishing, than making it a habit. There is also Custom Web Setup projects that you could create in Visual Studio.
http://chriscant.phdcc.com/2009/01/custom-vs-web-setup-projects.html

Its more of  trade off between spending time in creating and maintaining this project between remembering to update the project everytime you publish.